# UIView width is bigger with UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

I have an `UIPageViewController` with `iCarousel` UIView on it.

I have a problem that when the user scrolls to one side (the "dead" side - index -1) the carousel is still visible for some reason, does anybody knows why is it?

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set clipsToBounds (clip subviews in storyboard) property to YES to view you add iCarousel on it